# How can change the security option in task scheduler using powershell

Tags: php, powershell, security, windows-task-scheduler

I called PowerShell script from the PHP page like below:

file.php

```
try{
   echo shell_exec('powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -File "C:\wamp64\www\xpress_upgrade\Schedule_CRON.ps1"');
   }catch (Exception $e){
    echo "Oops: Something went wrong.<br />".$e->getMessage();
   }
```

in my PowerShell script, I'm reading the inputs from the .txt file and creating a number of tasks based on the id.Below is my PowerShell script.

```
$lines = Get-Content C:\wamp64\www\xpress_upgrade\Scheduled_data.txt | Where {$_ -notmatch '^\s+$'} 
foreach ($line in $lines) {
    $fields = $line -split '\s+'
    $id = $fields[0]
    $time = $fields[1]  
    $description = "scheduled workflow " + $id
       
    #creating tasks in task scheduler on Workflow scheduled time
    $argument = 'C:\wamp64\www\xpress_upgrade\workflow_execution_progress_sch.php ' + $id
    Write-Host $argument
    $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.9\php.exe' -Argument $argument
    $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At $time
    Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName $description -Description $description 
}
```

If I run the PowerShell directly task is creating and working fine. but if I run via PHP file task is creating fine but it's not running due to below security issues. *Need to set user account name and set run the user is logged on or not.* - how can achieve this?

[image]
Warning in Task scheduler:

> Task Scheduler did not launch task "\WMS scheduled workflow 01"
> because user "**" was not logged on when the launching conditions were
> met. User Action: Ensure user is logged on or change the task
> definition to allow launching when user is logged off.

Comment: If you want the second option, then you need to run `Register-ScheduledTask` with the `-User` and `-Password` parameters. This means that you will need to either supply the credentials via an interactive prompt, store the credentials in  your current session and retrieve them, or store the credentials elsewhere and retrieve them when the command is called.

Comment: Anyway to do without mentioning user and password.@AdminOfThings . And i am not sure how to give use commands from [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in Register-ScheduledTask